# Ruby: is there a way to mock only existsted methods of class, but not all?

Tags: ruby, interface, mocking

Is there a way to mock only existed methods of class (with correct count of arguments), but not all? I want to test that I use existed methods with correct count of arguments, even if objects are mocked.

I'm using ruby 1.9.3 and mocha (0.11.1) for testing.

```
class A
  def a
    return 1
  end
end

... 

def test_...
  object = A.new # or object = mock( '::A' )
  object.expects( :a ) # ok

  object.expects( :b ) # I want "no method error" to be raised...
  object.stubs( :c ) # And here too
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

```
Mocha::Configuration.prevent(:stubbing_non_existent_method)
```

P.S. http://marklunds.com/articles/one/429

P.P.S. Let me google that for myself :( http://bit.ly/JLrkZQ

Comment: Another way is use method "responds_like" (also known as "quacks_like"): http://gofreerange.com/mocha/docs/Mocha/Mock.html#responds_like-instance_method